# Error: Program type already present: androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, androidx

When I integrate the unity game on my android app, so application is run on my device easily but when I build the **apk** I get the following error.

[image: error screenshot]

I want to add a unity game on my existing android application.

```
implementation "androidx.collection:collection:$collection_version"
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    //    ANDROID LIBS
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
   //
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'



//  FACEBOOK LIB
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.1.1'

//  GPLUS LIB
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0") {
        exclude group: "android.arch.lifecycle"
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
//    FIREBASE LIBS
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.2'

//   AWS LIBS
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.31'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.31'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.31'

//    WEBSERVICE LIB
    implementation 'com.medy:retrofitwrapper:1.5.1'

//    IMAGE LOAD LIB
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'


//    OTHER LIBS
    implementation 'com.github.jineshfrancs:CaptchaImageView:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Ibotta:Supported-Picker-Dialogs:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.vihtarb:tooltip:0.2.0'
    implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

//    AUTO SCROLL VIEW PAGER
    implementation('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.5.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0") {
        exclude group: "android.arch.lifecycle"
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
```

Try with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0' // or 6.2.1
```